# +1 при нанажатии на кнопку

Tags: java, javafx

Есть кнопка и лейбл счетчика, нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку счетчик прибавлял 1 и отображал новое значение. Не могу понять где надо вводить переменную, пытался и внутри лямбды, и отдельным классом, и за setOnAction, но  консоль выдает "local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final".

```
myBtn.setOnAction(e -> {
  //логика
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если мы используем переменную внутри анонимного класса то она должна быть `final`. Это справедливо и для лямбд, потому что последние, по сути, тоже являются таковыми.

Есть несколько способов обойти данное ограничение:

- объявить `final` массив размером 1 с заданным типом
- использовать `mutable` объект, в вашем случае объявить переменную типа `AtomicInteger`

Переменная должна быть полем у класса.